# R: Plotting one column of a data frame with all the others using lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a data frame with some random data `x` and `y`. Where *x* is a *20x10* matrix and *y: 20x1*. 
Here is the head of the dataframe:

```
          V1         V2        V3        V4         V5         V6        V7
1 0.02817177 0.50219235 0.4380900 0.1016292 0.26199577 0.89682227 0.3329234
2 0.35670341 0.13153117 0.7640606 1.4032035 0.06884403 0.04999577 1.3631137
3 0.85262638 0.07891709 0.2619613 1.7767756 0.37888356 1.34534931 0.4691473
4 0.51336525 0.88678481 0.7734046 0.6228674 2.58195893 1.93121153 0.8428756
5 1.01820300 0.11697127 0.8143791 0.5222834 0.12983414 0.70958158 1.4579937
6 1.02147908 0.31863009 0.4384506 1.3222310 0.71302498 0.15790503 0.4003059
         V8        V9         V10       V11
1 0.7737134 0.4084250 0.242269499 1.2397228
2 0.4240024 2.1364939 0.059031382 0.5898739
3 0.5839470 0.1568219 0.177271868 0.1240193
4 0.4150357 0.6600489 0.794680268 0.5237078
5 1.5452617 0.9818344 0.006737787 0.6202280
6 0.5187495 1.1136437 0.629790293 0.7082216
```

What I want to do is plot `y=V1` with `x=V2`,

then `y=V1` with `x=V3`,

then `y=V1` with `x=V4` and so on.

I already wrote a reproducible code with `ggplot`, here is the code:

```
set.seed(100)
x=matrix(rnorm(20*10, mean = 0, sd=1), ncol=10)
y=matrix(rnorm(20, mean = 0, sd=1), ncol=1)
x=abs(x)
y=abs(y)
df=as.data.frame(cbind(y,x))
#plotting
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=V2, y=V1, group=1)) +geom_line()
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=V2, y=V1, group=1)) +geom_line()
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=V3, y=V1, group=1)) +geom_line()
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=V4, y=V1, group=1)) +geom_line()
```

Is there any way to write just one line `ggplot(data=df, aes(x=V2, y=V1, group=1)) +geom_line()` for every value of x? I tried it with a loop but it didn't really work. 
And how could I add all these lines that I get into on e plot just, not separate plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make one column of x values, then use the `group` parameter to tell `ggplot` which line they belong to:

```
df2 <- tidyr::gather(df, "x_group", "x_val", V2:V11)
head(df2)
#           V1 x_group      x_val
# 1 0.02817177      V2 0.50219235
# 2 0.35670341      V2 0.13153117
# 3 0.85262638      V2 0.07891709
# 4 0.51336525      V2 0.88678481
# 5 1.01820300      V2 0.11697127
# 6 1.02147908      V2 0.31863009

ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=x_val, y=V1, group=x_group, color = x_group)) + geom_line()
```

[image: lines colored by group]

Comment: there is just one redundant bracket in `ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=x_val, y=V1, group=x_group, color = x_group)))`